# Как по разному оформить :focus при табе и при активации мышкой?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

На главной странице [Яндекса](https://yandex.ua) если перемещаться по странице с помощью клавиатуры, нажимая TAB, интерактивные элементы получают желтую обводку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если кликнуть мышкой по ссылкам, то желтой обводки нет, не смотря на то, что при активации мышкой элемент тоже получает **`focus`** и желтая обводка по идее должна быть. Как они сделали, что стили при фокусе применяются только если этот фокус сделан с клавиатуры табом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так происходит, потому что жёлтая обводка появляется при помощи добавления класса содержащего обводку. Класс добавляется с помощью `JS`. Наподобие:

```js
$('a').on('focus blur', function(evt) {
  $(this).toggleClass('focus', evt.type === 'focus');
});
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

a.focus {
  outline: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a tabindex="1" href="#">1</a>
<a tabindex="4" href="#">4</a>
<a tabindex="2" href="#">2</a>
<a tabindex="5" href="#">5</a>
<a tabindex="3" href="#">3</a>
```

Только у них написана функция, которая определяет был ли клик, в фокусе ли элемент от мышки или от таба, и если от таба, или на мобильном устройстве, то добавляется класс.